# eclipse binary not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I have installed eclipse c/c++ mars (last version),i installed minGW,added it's path to windows path,updated java,added minGW path in eclipse itself,checked cdt gcc built-in compiler settings,also the cdt cross gcc bulit-in compiler settings.

But,as u can see from picture,looks like eclipse can't identify built-in keywords of c++,also gave me error : launch failed.binary not found

I googled the problem and read many errors here on stackoverflow,and tried each but in vain

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtlQY.png)

Comment: Heh. Did the same thing about the same time. I got that error, but it seemed to sort itself out after a save, a build, and a few minutes.

Comment: i did that also with no effect

Comment: I: installed java. Installed mingw. Installed Eclipse java. Installed CDT into Eclipse. Made a test program. Couldn't select mingw toolchain. Smacked forehead. Added mingw's bin and mingw's msys bin to the path. Made a test program. Waited for indexing or whatever to finish. built and ran program.

Comment: Did you check Window/Preferences C++/ Build/Settings discovery
Command is {COMMAND} ?
Check the check-box allocate Console. On press apply you see a valid message that eclipse start g++ and extract path and symbols ...

After this you should see all internal include path in Project Settings/c++ General/preprocessor include Language c++
Entry CDT builtin Compiler Settings.

There should no error Message: toolchain not found.

Answer (score 0):

On the menu bar, Go to Project >> Build All

Your code is actually just text, not code. When you build that text, Eclipse will convert that text into actual C++ code.